# Is there a way to run DNN 9with MySql database by changing the connection point?

Tags: mysql, dotnetnuke

I've been searching online for a way to run DNN with mysql database but most of the stuff I found dates back to 10 or 15 years ago.

My question is this. I am currently running DNN 9 with MS SQL express. But due to the lack of storage on SQL express, I am looking for ways to connect my DNN 9 with MySql.

I am opening my options to running previous version/build. I don't have to worry about updates as once the connection is linked (DNN with mysql), it will stay on that version forever.

ps. If this is the wrong place to ask I will take it down as soon as possible

I have tried www.aspfree.com/c/a/database/how-to-install-dotnetnuke-with-mysql/ method which was the only one I found with guidelines. But it's quite old and the version they used were DNN 4 and MySQL 5.1.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to do this. DNN is meant for MS SQL. Even if you got it working somehow you probably run into problems later on with specific functions/modules.

But Express is free up to 10 gb. Maybe split the DNN core content and the data that is taking up so much space.

You can create modules that connect to external databases. Some of them are already in the DNN store. Maybe the solution lies in there.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way, but I am not sure if you really want to do this. DNN is built on a provider model, and there is a piece "between" the business layer and the database itself called the Data Provider. This is responsible for getting data from and writing data to the database, executing Stored Procedures and so on. DNN is delivered with a data provider for MS SQL Server, but it is possible to write a Data Provider for any other database (mySQL, Oracle...) as well.

Beside the Data Provider, you have to adapt all the SQL scripts for DNN and any module you use to make the target database understand it.

And you have to do that for every new version of DNN and all the modules.

There were projects in the early years of DNN that tried to implement a Data Provider for mySQL, and others for Oracle - they all gave up somewhen.

Happy DNNing!
Michael